# Accessing a request header from inside a custom PostSharp attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postsharp

I'm trying to access a `HttpRequestMessage` from inside a custom PostSharp attribute.

In my Web API I could do it like this:

```
string headerText = Request.Headers.GetValues("TestHeader").First();
```

This doesn't seem to work outside of the API controller.

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class LogHeaderAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Log Web API request header info here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I can access the headers this way:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class LogHeaderAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        ApiController apiController = (ApiController)args.Instance;
        var context = apiController.ControllerContext;
        HttpRequestHeaders headers = context.Request.Headers;

        // Use Web API request header info here
        string headerText = headers.GetValues("MyHeader").First();
    }
}
```